# How do I create subdomain names dynamically php script in ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, virtualhost, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I would like to be able to create subdomain name dynamically using PHP.I am using ubuntu server (Alibaba cloud server).
Example:

> http://subdomain.example.com

please help me.

Comment: this is not just a LAMP server problem... this is also a DNS problem... since you need to register an "A Record" in your DNS...

Comment: What's your scenario? It is about web application development or you want to build your own domain name server.